# Why Tomcat freezes and leaks memory when getting an Oracle connection from a pool?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, memory, connection-pooling

We’re facing a problem related to Oracle connection pooling on Apache Tomcat. Everything works fine at the first attempt to get a connection. However, the second attempt takes a lot of time and the memory usage of the Apache Tomcat process increases until it crashes the system.

#### Environment:

- Windows 10 (Same problem on Linux)
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.25
- JDK 1.6.0_45
- Oracle Instant Client 64-bit - 11.2.0.3.0
- Eclipse Luna

#### server.xml setup:

```
<Resource auth="Container"
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
          maxActive="60" 
          maxIdle="10" 
          maxWaitMillis="10000" 
          name="jdbc/TEST" 
          password="test" 
          removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
          type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
          url="jdbc:oracle:oci:@test"
          userName="test"/>
```

#### context.xml setup:

```
<ResourceLink auth="Container" 
              global="jdbc/TEST"
              name="jdbc/TEST"
              type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
```

**The source code to get connection:**

```
public static Connection connect(ServersConnectionsEnum servidor)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/"
                    + servidor.getJndiName());
            return ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Before you ask, the connection is properly closed after its use is done, on a `finally` block.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    try{ rs.close(); } catch( Exception e ){ logger.error(e.getMessage(), e); }

    try{ stmt.close(); } catch( Exception e ){ logger.error(e.getMessage(), e); }

    try { if( conn != null && !conn.isClosed() ) { conn.close(); } } catch( Exception e ){ logger.error(e.getMessage(), e); }
}
```

**References:**

[Tomcat 7 JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

**PS:** There's nothing on Tomcat's log.

Comment: If there's nothing in the log, how do you know it's the connection that's causing the problem? What else is the code doing, and have you added debugs to narrow it down to that `getConnection()` call? Can you see session(s) for the test user in the DB, being created and freed when you expect?

Comment: Hi Alex Poole. I tracked it with a debug point on getConnection method. At this point the system stay processing for a indefinitely time and increase the memory.

Comment: Please learn how to use try-with-resources, your try-catch example is really brittle and try with resources will remove a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the question clearly states he's working with Java 6. Try with resources is a Java 7 idiom.

Comment: @CássioRenan True, but he could upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried using [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.html) and [getPooledConnection()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.html#getPooledConnection__)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I use try with resources in others projects. But I can't on this one, upgrade isn't an option for now. Thanks for your comment.

Could anyone help me about the problem itself?

Comment: @CássioRenan That is not what a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is for; it should **not** be used directly in an application. It is for a connection pool implementation to get connections to be used in the connection pool, it is not a connection pool itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have anything to go on. I'd start with a profiler to find out what is consuming memory and where it is allocated. I'd be very surprised if it is anything in Tomcat or Oracle. However, you might want to check if a newer version of Tomcat 7 (latest is 7.0.85) help (I see several notes in their release notes about memory leaks, but none are directly related to the JDBC pool).

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel. Update the server or change it to Wildfly is an option. However, this have other impacts that we want to avoid.

Comment: @CássioRenan, unfortunately, same result with using OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.

Comment: Debugging I found where the thread stops. It's when is invoked the T2CConnection.logon() method.

Comment: Please switch to the JDBC-thin driver which should always be preferred compared to JDBC-OCI. JDBC-thin is what most people use. It's optimized and has a lot more code coverage than JDBC-OCI.

Comment: Just for note, I installed the JDK 1.6.0_23 for Tomcat and JDK 1.8.0_162 for IDE and everything works fine. I really don't understand why it happened.